# Given A and B as square matrices is A solvable in ABA = C?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Say we have 3 square matrices A, B, C and equation ABA = C. Can A be solved? If A were solvable for square matrices, would A be solvable for non-square matrices?

Comment: Consider a trivial example of if $B=C=0$.  Then every matrix $A$ would make this true.  For a less trivial example, consider the example of $B=C=I$.  You would be asking if we could solve $A^2=I$ uniquely.  We cannot.  There are many solutions.  Similarly there can be multiple solutions for other scenarios, or even no solutions for other scenarios, such as if $B=0$ and $C=I$.

Answer (score 2):

For general square matrix, the answer is no. This is because there are usually infinitely many square roots for a given matrix.

However, if $B$ is positive definite and $C$ is positive semi-definite, then there is an unique positive semi-definite $A$ which satisfies $ABA = C$.

Recall for any positive semi-definite matrix $M$, there is an unique positive semi-definite matrix $N$ which satisfies $N^2 = M$. We will use $\sqrt{M}$ to refer to this unique square root. In terms of this square root operation over positive semi-definite matrices, 
we have

$$\begin{align}
ABA = C &\implies (\sqrt{B}A\sqrt{B})^2 = \sqrt{B}A\sqrt{B}^2A\sqrt{B} = \sqrt{B}C\sqrt{B}\\
& \implies \sqrt{B}A\sqrt{B} = \sqrt{\sqrt{B}C\sqrt{B}}\\
& \implies A = \sqrt{B}^{-1} \sqrt{\sqrt{B}C\sqrt{B}}\sqrt{B}^{-1}
\end{align}$$